# Add a condition to mysql query in order to prevent viewing the content

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query

```
$req = $mysqli->query(
"SELECT * FROM informations 
   WHERE id='$id' AND ((type='0' AND userid_one = '$uid') OR 
     (type='1' AND  (userid_two='$uid' OR userid_one='$uid')))");
```

**My need:**

I want to show some informations to `userid_one` and others to `userid_two` and prevent `userid_two` to view the content only when `type='0'` and `userid_one='$uid'`.

**But in this cases we show the contents:**

- `type='1'` and `userid_one='$uid'`
- `type='1'` and `userid_two='$uid'`
- `type='0'` and `userid_one='$uid'`

Comment: We need more context. Data may help for current data and desired results. Can a user fall in `userid_one` and `userid_two` at the same time? You give the forbidden rule for `userid_two` but what is the permission rule for `userid_one`? Even more, of the cases you list, which ones are not allowed?

Comment: There only one `not allowed` condition and is: `type='0'` and `userid_one!='$uid'`, and the `allowed` one are the 3 listed in the post.